# keep longest isoforms - multiple keys in dictionary with python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the smallest isoforms from a very long list because I only want to use the longest.
Here is how my data looks like:

```
comp30035   seq1    608 
comp30037   seq1    265 
comp3003    seq1    298 
comp30043   seq1    236 
comp30043   seq3    529 
comp30043   seq4    315 
comp30043   seq5    1120
```

For the contigs with only one isoform (e.g only seq1), no problem but many of them have many isoforms (seq2,3 …). For example for config comp30043 I only want to keep in my list the seq5 which is the longest.

I want to keep only the longest one of them and obviously I need to keep the one with only one isoform.

I was thinking about using a python dictionary, with the contigs name as key and isoform name and length has values but I don't have any experience with multiple values.

Any hints and help to get me started is very much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Could you post the **full output** you want? Just to make the question clearer.

Comment: sure, with this example I would just want a list of the contigs name like: comp30035_seq1, comp30037_seq1, comp3003_seq1, comp30043_seq5

Comment: What is an "isoform"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use tuples as values for your dictionary. Alternatively, you could even use a dictionary itself as a value to one. Here's a snippet of code[probably more readable than efficient], that'll do the former.

Assuming you've saved your data in contigsFile.txt:

```
contigDict = {}
for line in open('contigsFile.txt'):
    contigId, isoform, length = line.split()
    if contigId in contigDict:
        curr_Isoform, curr_length = contigDict[contigId]
        if int(curr_length) < int(length):
            contigDict[contigId] = (isoform, length)
    else:
        contigDict[contigId] = (isoform, length)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, I will try to comment it, so you can understand it easily.

I used a dictionary to store elements in the form: `{"compxxxx" : ("seqx", number)}`

```
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.split() for line in f] # List of lists, each nested list contains strings
    result = {} # To store result
    for l in lines: # For each nested list
        if l[0] not in result: # If the 'key'(compxxxx) is not in 'result'
            result[l[0]] = (l[1], int(l[2])) # Add elements to 'result'. Note the int cast of the 'number'
        elif l[2] > result[l[0]][1]: # If 'key' is in 'result' check if 'number' is higher
            result[l[0]] = (l[1], int(l[2]))

    for k, v in result.iteritems(): # To print elements
        print k, v
```

**Output:**

```
comp30035 ('seq1', 608)
comp30043 ('seq5', 1120)
comp30037 ('seq1', 265)
comp3003 ('seq1', 298)
```

Comment: Wow this seems to work absolutely perfectly, I am totally impressed! I am just going to modify it a bit so the output is easier for me later on, but thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept this answer if it was useful and solved your problem: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Just a quick question, what are k and v here? and how does inter items work? I am interested to fully understand it

Comment: When looping through dictionaries, the key and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same time using the `iteritems()` method of dictionaries. I really recommend you to read [Python docs, search for `iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and you will find a nice example.